# SQL query: Fill missing values with 0

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table with gaps in data at certain times (see there is no data between 37 & 46). I need to fill in those gaps with 0 for better display on the frontend.

```
  date  |          mydata 
--------+-----------------
 911130 |              10
 911131 |              11
 911132 |               9
 911133 |               6
 911134 |               5
 911135 |               5
 911136 |              10
 911137 |               8
 911146 |               4
 911147 |               5
 911148 |               9
 911149 |              14
 911150 |               8
```

The times are sequential integers (UNIX timestamps initially). I have aggregated my data into 5 minute time buckets.
The frontend query will pass in a start & end time and aggregate the data into larger buckets. For example:

```
  SELECT
    (five_min_time / 6) AS date,
    SUM(mydata) AS mydata
  FROM mydata_table_five_min
  WHERE 
    five_min_time BETWEEN (1640000000 / 300) AND (1640086400 / 300)
  GROUP BY date
  ORDER BY date ASC;
```

I would like to be able to get a result:

```
  date  |          mydata 
--------+-----------------
 911130 |              10
 911131 |              11
 911132 |               9
 911133 |               6
 911134 |               5
 911135 |               5
 911136 |              10
 911137 |               8
 911138 |               0
 911139 |               0
 911140 |               0
 911141 |               0
 911142 |               0
 911143 |               0
 911144 |               0
 911145 |               0
 911146 |               4
 911147 |               5
 911148 |               9
 911149 |              14
 911150 |               8
```

As a note, this query is being run in AWS Redshift.

Comment: Since generate_series is not reliable on redshift, you could try something like this: 
http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/redshift-sequential-generate-series-numbers-time.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a recursive CTE works in redshift.
But something like this works in postgresql.

> ```
> with recursive rcte as (
>   select 
>   min(half_hour) as n,
>   max(half_hour) as n_max
>   from cte_data
>   union all
>   select n+1, n_max
>   from rcte
>   where n < n_max
> )
> , cte_data as (
>   select 
>    (five_min_time / 6) as half_hour, 
>    sum(mydata) as mydata
>   from mydata_table_five_min
>   where five_min_time between (date_part('epoch','2021-12-20 12:00'::date)::int / 300) 
>                           and (date_part('epoch','2021-12-21 12:00'::date)::int / 300)
>   group by half_hour
> )
>
> select n as date
> --, to_timestamp(n*6*300) as dt
> , coalesce(t.mydata, 0) as mydata
> from rcte c
> left join cte_data t
>   on t.half_hour = c.n
> order by date;
> ```

Comment: Yes, recursive CTEs work in Redshift.